# RegEx for square brackets' string but not vector's index, it's possible?

Tags: regex, string, vector, brackets, square-bracket

I'm using Habour in Sublime Text 3.

How can I create a regex for square brackets string like below:

```
a:= [text] // same as a:= "text"
b:= [3] // same as b:= "3"
c:= {2,[text]} // same as c:= {2,"text"}
d:=[text]  // same as d:="text"
Funtion([text]) // Same as Function("text")
```

but not include vector index, like:

```
aVet[index] // Same as aVet[1], aVet[2]...
e:= aVet[index] // Same as aVet[1], aVet[2]...
f:= aVet[2,3] // Same as aVet[1,2], aVet[2,5]...
g:= aVet[CONSTANT] // Same as aVet[FOO], aVet[BAR]...
```

Comment: 3 questions: 1. What EXACT rules dictate when to replace and when not to? 2. Why regex? 3. If you have a good answer for 2, which flavor?

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]\s*(\[.*?\])
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jY0sB4/3)

Answer (score 0):

### [`vet\[.*?\]|(\[.*?\])`](https://regex101.com/r/uM2oC2/1)

This assumes that vector indices always starts with a `vet`. You must add a tag of whichever language you're using to clear up this confusion. Anyway, the the code above should do the trick. Follow the link for a detailed breakdown of what's happening behind the curtain.

The code above might not be that intuitive, but the basic idea is this: the engine looks for the statements that has the word `vet` followed by square brackets in it. If there is one it matches it. If it doesn't it captures the one on the right side (what we want). The only issue is, if you add comments in your code that has square brackets in them, it might capture those too. If you plan to do so, the regex needs to be modified for more conditions, but this will work as long you don't do that. Let me know if that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

first things, first. I'm using Harbour in Sublime Text 3.

iismathwizard, your code almost does the magic.

> [^a-zA-Z0-9\s]\s*([.*?])

It always gets the first character before the right's square brackets, like:

"=" in a, b and d examples

"," in c example

"(" in function example

However, it doesn't gets any vector's index.

user41235, your code not exclude the vector's index.

> vet[.*?]|([.*?])

I added a few examples for more detail.

Sorry my english...